# try-with-resources gives unexpected incompatibility errors

Tags: java, javadb

Executing `javac JdbcRowSet.java` on the following excerpt confuses me:

```
//
import javax.sql.*;
import javax.sql.rowset.*;
import java.sql.*;

class JdbcRowSet
{
    public static void main(String ... args){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try(JdbcRowSet jrs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createJdbcRowSet()){
            //CODE
}
//
```

According to JavaDoc:

`public interface ResultSet extends Wrapper, AutoCloseable`

`public interface RowSet extends ResultSet`

`public interface JdbcRowSet extends RowSet, Joinable`

I got the following errors:

```
dbcRowSet.java:8:error: incompatible types: javax.sql.rowset.JdbcRowSet cannot be converted to JdbcRowSet try(//)
JdbcRowSet.java:8:error: incompatible types: try-with-resources not applicable to variable type
JdbcRowSet cannot be converted to AutoCloseable.
```

The errors are strangely confusing. Can someone help me on this.
Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `JdbcRowSet` as the name of your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kayaman correctly pointed out in his comment - you are declaring  your own `JdbcRowSet` class.

Either change the name of the class or fully qualify the object in the `try`.

```
try(javax.sql.rowset.JdbcRowSet jrs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createJdbcRowSet())
```

Comment: thanks OldCurmudgeon. i appreciated your help. ISelf study purpose only and no claim of any kind of proficiency.